# How to display popup from code-behind in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

I wonder how it would be possible to launch a series of popups, containing a form,
from code-behind.

I possess a list of objects 'Products'

and I wish I could change one property (quantity) of each "product".

Here's how I build my list (normally I use a database).

```
Private List<Product> listProduct;


    listProduits = new List<Product>();

    Product objProduit_1 = new Produit;

    objProduct_1.ref = "001";
    objProduct_1.article = "G900";
    objProduct_1.quantity = 30;

    listProducts.Add(objProduct_1);

    ProductobjProduit_2 = new Product;

    objProduct_2.ref = "002";
    objProduct_2.article = "G900";
    objProduct_2.quantity = 35;

    listProduits.Add(objProduct_2);
```

And I would like displayed popup one after one.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to write some client side code that produces what you're looking for. The AJAX Control tool kit may be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this part of answer, I'll look in that direction.